# TokenResponseException: missing scope when using the RemoteAPI of AppEngine in Java with OAuth 2.0 on stand-alone application

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-oauth

My goal is for my stand-alone application to access the datastore of a Google App Engine application so that I can query it. My application used to work with ClientLogin, but I have been asked to use OAuth 2.0 for the authentication (and using ClientLogin doesn't work anymore).

I follow the instructions on this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi

I use the provided code, have made an *service account*, downloaded the json key, made an environment variable pointing to this key. The result is that I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at myApplication.myClass4.moveResultsOfFeature(myClass4.java:51)
    at myApplication.myClass2.migrate(MyClass3.java:32)
    at myApplication.myClass1.main(Starter.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to acquire Google Application Default credential.
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions.useApplicationDefaultCredential(RemoteApiOptions.java:163)
    at commonMigration.RemoteOptions.<clinit>(RemoteOptions.java:18)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "invalid_scope",
  "error_description" : "Empty or missing scope not allowed."
}
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:287)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:307)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:384)
    at com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:489)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.remoteapi.RemoteApiOptions.useApplicationDefaultCredential(RemoteApiOptions.java:160)
    ... 4 more
```

which seems to point to a missing scope argument, a concern which isn't mentioned in the explication on the web page. Is there an easy way to fix this issue?

Per request, my code (simplified):

```
public class StackOverflow {

    private static RemoteApiOptions REMOTE_OPTIONS = new RemoteApiOptions().server(
            <application-id>.appspot.com, 443)
            .useApplicationDefaultCredential();

    public static void main(String[] args0) throws IOException {
        // MAKING THE CONNECTION
        RemoteApiInstaller installer = new RemoteApiInstaller();
        // LOAD FROM Local
        installer.install(REMOTE_OPTIONS);
        try {
            // MY OPERATIONS 
        } finally {
            installer.uninstall();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please show your code?

Comment: Sure, I've just put it as an edit.

Answer (score 1):

This is a current limitation of the Remote API. See the note [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/remoteapi#configuring_remote_api_on_a_standalone_client):

> Note: The Remote API call to useApplicationDefaultCredential() can only use credentials provided by the gcloud command.

(It's possible you followed the instructions before the note was added, since it is a recently discovered limitation). The limitation will be fixed in a future release. For now, you should either run:

```
gcloud auth login
```

And use your user account to authenticate using `useApplicationDefaultCredential()`. Or, you can use a service account with `.useServiceAccountCredential`, which accepts the service account email and a path to a `p12` file instead of the `json` file.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I already performed the check. I've had a PhD look at it, and his conclusions were that the OAuth 2.0 in Java wasn't complete; There are holes in the guide. Among other things, setting the path to the p12 or json file as an environment variable didn't do the trick.

Comment: When using a p12 hey you need to use a different method call on the remote API which properly sets the scopes. The scopes are not properly set when using `useApplicationDefaultCredentials`

Comment: Strange you say that. I've myself only used json files, but as you can see from my original post, the error was also a missing scope. Can you tell me what those different method calls are?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer: `RemoteApiOptions` has two separate methods: `useApplicationDefaultCredential()`, which pulls your service account credentials from a json file specified by the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable. This does *not* work right now due to missing scopes. Instead, use `useServiceAccountCredential(...)` which accepts a service account email and the path to a p12 private key file. This method *does* set the scopes properly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have a look!

Comment: Does useServiceAccountCredential works with P12 file. I am trying to use it in Java and get error com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 302 Found.